# using IPy to read through data frame and return if public or private ip

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a set of logs with random ip information and other things.  Im making these logs into data frames and then trying to read the IP information afterwards and return if they are public or private its through running them with IPy.  Im getting back an error and can't figure it out.

My coding looks like this

```
df2 = pd.read_csv( 'p0f.txt',sep='|',header=0, engine='python')
df2.columns = ['time','client_ip','server_ip','d','connection','mtu','g','raw_ip']
df2['client_ip'] = df2['client_ip'].map(lambda x: str(x)[4:])
df2['server_ip'] = df2['server_ip'].map(lambda x: str(x)[4:])
df2['mtu'] = df2['mtu'].map(lambda x:  x.lstrip('raw_mtu=langEnglishnonefreqdistHz').rstrip('=Hz'))
df2['time'] = df2['time'].map(lambda x:  x.lstrip('').rstrip('mod=mtu,cli=mod=syn+ackmod=uptimemod=httpreqmod= httpmod=host chang'))
df2_client_ip =  df2[['client_ip']]
df_client_ip_check = df.applymap(lambda x: IP(x).iptype())
```

when I print I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mykelxknight/CodeProjects/chiron/BroHttpParse.py", line 44, in <module>
    df_client_ip_check = df.applymap(lambda x: IP(x).iptype())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4453, in applymap
    return self.apply(infer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4262, in apply
    ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4358, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4451, in infer
    return lib.map_infer(x.asobject, func)
  File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas/_libs/lib.c:66645)
  File "/Users/mykelxknight/CodeProjects/chiron/BroHttpParse.py", line 44, in <lambda>
    df_client_ip_check = df.applymap(lambda x: IP(x).iptype())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPy.py", line 246, in __init__
    (self.ip, parsedVersion) = parseAddress(ip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPy.py", line 1417, in parseAddress
    raise ValueError("%r: single byte must be 0 <= byte < 256" % (ipstr))
ValueError: ("'1433937432.495592': single byte must be 0 <= byte < 256", 'occurred at index #fields')
```